# When to close channels

Tags: go, concurrency, threadpool

Looking through some examples of worker pools in Go, I couldn't identify a consistent approach to closing channels. For example, this [project on Github](https://github.com/gammazero/workerpool/blob/019d125201abcf1a535142d07591da5c4be74bd6/workerpool.go#L218) seems to close all channels, while this [similar implementation](https://riptutorial.com/go/example/18325/job-queue-with-worker-pool#example) does not once close a channel! I know that closing a channel indicates completion; no more values can be sent on it. But is it just a runtime assertion? Don't open channels also leave behind memory leaks? Or do you just rely on garbage collection? And where would I close the channels opened in the second example if I were to do it explicitly?

Comment: "Channels aren't like files; you don't usually need to close them. Closing is only necessary when the receiver must be told there are no more values coming, such as to terminate a range loop." https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4

Comment: Thank you! It would still be interesting to know how to close the channels in the second example. Especially how to properly close the nested channels in `readyPool`.

Answer (score 0):

Channels can be used any way you like:

- If you are sending a finite number of items, closing the channel indicates to the listener no more items are coming
- if you implementing a continuous stream (micro-service etc) the channel will never be closed.
- a channels close event can be used to signal an event

Note: You do *not* have to close a channel for it to be garbage collected. Once the channel goes out of scope on the producer & consumer sides, it will be reclaimed, even if there are unread items on the channel.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I conclude that closing the channels in the Github project I linked just helps with the cleanup in case the user forgets to dereference the whole pool after stopping it (because it can be started only once).